# Copy files from ALDS Gen2 to SFTP using data factory without SSH (?)

Tags: azure, ssh, cloud, etl, azure-data-factory

Currently the only supported auth methods for the ADF SFTP Connector in the Microsoft docs are Basic, SSH Public key & multi-factor auth:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory

The provider of the SFTP says they have disabled SSH for security purposes.

Is there a way for ADF to copy files to an SFTP without using SSH?? I have considered mounting the SFTP onto an Integration Runtime VM using NetDrive, and using that as the sink, but am hoping there are other, less convoluted, alternatives...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While deploying the SFTP Linked Service, you can choose `Disable the SSH host key Validation` under SSH Host Key Validation option and simply choose `Basic` Authentication type by providing **Username** and **Password** for your SFTP connection.

Refer below sample Linked Service.

[image]