# How to create api in azure that uploads file from SFTP to azure data lake storage

Tags: azure, api, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-apps

My requirement is I want to create api/azure function for uploading file from SFTP server to azure data lake storage is there any refference projects or guidences please guide me

Answer (score 0):

***Yes, you can achieve the above requirement to connect and transfer the files from SFTP to Data lake storage*** ;

*Please check if my findings are helpful,*

*You can do  while uploading files to Data Lake through SFTP server the configuration of* ***authentication is set to basic and disable SSH host keys validation this is when you are trying to upload files using without any authentication with Azure AD*** .

For example:-

[image]

*When you are trying to upload files to DATA LAKE Storage through SFTP you need to configure SFTP on Portal and provide the connection details .*

*For complete configuration and information please find the below workaround links :-*

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***Copy and transform data in SFTP server using Azure Data Factory***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp?tabs=data-factory) & [***Use .NET to manage directories and files in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet).
- **SO THREAD**|[***Copy files from ALDS Gen2 to SFTP using data factory without SSH***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72037700/copy-files-from-alds-gen2-to-sftp-using-data-factory-without-ssh)
- **GitHub Blog**|[**how to ingest data from an SFTP source to your Azure Data Lake**](https://github.com/davedoesdemos/SFTPIngest/blob/master/SFTPIngest.md)